# Getting a Semantic Error in Hive " Expression not in GROUP BY key 'Cust_intrl_ID'

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

The following query has an error in Line 4 (Expression not in GROUP BY key 'Cust_intrl_ID'):

```
SELECT
    Cust_intrl_ID,
    customer_no,
    cust_type_cd
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Cust_intrl_ID,
            customer_no,
            cust_cust_type_cd,
            year(trxn_exctn_dt) year,
            month(trxn_exctn_dt) month,
            sum(w.trxn_base_am)
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    cust.Cust_intrl_ID Cust_intrl_id,
                    regexp_replace(w.cstm_4_tx, "^0+(?!$)", "") customer_no,
                    year(w.trxn_exctn_dt) year,
                    month(w.trxn_exctn_dt) month,
                    sum(w.trxn_base_am) amt,
                    ca.cust_acct_role_cd cust_acct_role_cd,
                    cust.cstm_4_tx cstm_4_tx,
                    ca.acct_intrl_id acct_intrl_id
                FROM
                    l4_amlmntcbnn.Wire_trxn w
                    INNER JOIN l4_amlmntcbnn.acct a on a.eap_as_of_dt = '2021-01'
                    and a.Acct_intrl_ID = w.Benef_acct_ID
                    and a.acct_type1_cd <> 'IPB'
                    and substring(a.jrsdcn_cd, 0, 2) <> 'LA'
                    INNER JOIN l4_amlmntcbnn.cust_acct ca on ca.eap_as_of_dt = a.eap_as_of_dt
                    and ca.Acct_intrl_ID = a.Acct_intrl_ID
                    INNER JOIN l4_amlmntcbnn.cust on ca.eap_as_of_dt = cust.eap_as_of_dt
                    and ca.cust_intrl_ID = cust.cust_intrl_ID
                    and cust.cust_type_cd = 'IND'
                WHERE
                    w.trxn_exctn_dt between '2020-07-01'
                    and '2020-12-31'
                    and w.frgn_trxn_fl = 'Y'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    cust.Cust_intrl_ID,
                    regexp_replace(w.cstm_4_tx, "^0+(?!$)", "") customer_no,
                    year(w.trxn_exctn_dt) year,
                    month(w.trxn_exctn_dt) month,
                    sum(w.trxn_base_am) amt,
                    ca.cust_acct_role_cd cust_acct_role_cd,
                    cust.cstm_4_tx cstm_4_tx,
                    ca.acct_intrl_id acct_intrl_id
                FROM
                    l4_amlmntcbnn.Wire_trxn w
                    INNER JOIN l4_amlmntcbnn.acct a on a.eap_as_of_dt = '2021-01'
                    and a.Acct_intrl_ID = w.Orig_acct_ID
                    and a.acct_type1_cd <> 'IPB'
                    and substring(a.jrsdcn_cd, 0, 2) <> 'LA'
                    INNER JOIN l4_amlmntcbnn.cust_acct ca on ca.eap_as_of_dt = a.eap_as_of_dt
                    and ca.Acct_intrl_ID = a.Acct_intrl_ID
                    INNER JOIN l4_amlmntcbnn.cust on ca.eap_as_of_dt = cust.eap_as_of_dt
                    and ca.cust_intrl_ID = cust.cust_intrl_ID
                    and cust.cust_type_cd = 'IND'
                WHERE
                    w.trxn_exctn_dt between '2020-07-01'
                    and '2020-12-31'
                    and w.frgn_trxn_fl = 'Y'
            ) w
        GROUP BY
            Cust_intrl_ID,
            regexp_replace(w.cstm_4_tx, "^0+(?!$)", ""),
            year(w.trxn_exctn_dt),
            month(w.trxn_exctn_dt),
            ca.cust_acct_role_cd,
            cust.cstm_4_tx,
            ca.acct_intrl_id
        having
            sum(w.trxn_base_am) >= 9000
    ) t
GROUP BY
    Cust_intrl_ID,
    customer_no,
    cust_acct_role_cd,
    cstm_4_tx,
    acct_intrl_id
having
    count(*) >= 5
```

Comment: `cust_type_cd` column is not part of your group ( last group by ) so you can't list it as is. second its not output from your subquery

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch - but the group by clause is attempting to operate on columns that are not in the select clause

```
SELECT
    Cust_intrl_ID,
    customer_no,
    cust_type_cd
```

...

```
GROUP BY
    Cust_intrl_ID,
    customer_no,
    cust_acct_role_cd,
    cstm_4_tx,
    acct_intrl_id
```

Also the sum on sum(w.trxn_base_am) has no alias name -

As an aside - count(*) probably not a drama on this query - but you will find a performance improvement if you use count(1)